# Valgrind not working with select

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, select, valgrind

I'm having problems with valgrind and select. When I run my application in the terminal or when I run my application with gdb, I get no errors. Everything runs fine and as expected.

When I run my application with valgrind I get the following error:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./myservice
==3403== Thread 12:
==3403== Syscall param select(readfds) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3403==    at 0x41C3E31: ??? (syscall-template.S:81)
==3403==    by 0x805531B: myThread (myservice.c:2062)
==3403==    by 0x40CAF6F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==3403==    by 0x41CBBED: clone (clone.S:129)
==3403==  Address 0xf5c9f38 is on thread 12's stack
==3403==
```

My application itself will print out the following error:

```
Sep 15, 2015 | 10:30:32 | select: Bad file descriptor
```

I'm very new to valgrind so I don't have an understanding of what valgrind is doing to break the select. The relevant code is pasted below.

Global Pipe

```
int pipefd[2];
```

Interrupt Handler

```
void intHandler(int sig) {
    keepRunning = false;
    write(pipefd[1], "terminate", sizeof("terminate"));
}
```

Main

```
int main(int   argc, char *argv[]){
    int i = 0;
    ...
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);
    pipe(pipefd);
    ...
    pthread_t myThreadHandle[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pthread_create(&myThreadHandle[i], NULL, myThread, NULL);
    }
    ...
}
```

My Thread

```
void *myThread(void *ptr) {
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    ...
    int socketfd = 555; //edit: forgot to include socketfd code, this is the error
    ...
    fd_set readfs;
    FD_ZERO(&readfs);
    FD_SET(pipefd[0], &readfs);
    if(select(socketfd+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0){ //ln 2062
        snprintf(logMessage, sizeof(logMessage),"select: %s", strerror(errno));
        writeLog(logMessage);
    }
    ...
}
```

Essentially I want to terminate my application gracefully. I initialize the pipe in main and I use the pipe to monitor the select statements. Without writing to a pipe, the selects would sit idle until timeout. I use the signal handler to write to the pipe so my select statements will know the pipe has been written to and to stop waiting.

Is the problem with how I am using one pipe for multiple threads? From my understanding, select doesn't actually touch the data, only sees that it is there. So each thread should see the data on the pipe, modify its own fd_set and exit the select before the timeout (this is consistent with what I see in gdb).

**Fix (edit)** - Was using wrong nfds value for select, corrected by using the pipefd from readfs.

```
    if(select(pipefd[0]+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0){ //ln 2062
```

Comment: I think this is tricky without more code. You only add one FD to the set, yet pass `socketfd+1` as the number of FDs. What is the value of `socketfd`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem; I see a very different problem (inability to compile successfully), instead. Perhaps you meant to ask about that?

Comment: As it was said before, some more code would be useful. However, Valgrind can drastically change timings between threads (which I believe is in plus for testing purposes) and it may lead to some problems that were hidden so far.

Comment: Is `socketfd` possibly uninitialized or very large? valgrind will examine (arg1)/8 bytes worth of arg2 when processing the select system call.

Comment: @slugonamission (seems I can only notify one user) - Thank you all for the comments. You were all right. My socketfd is wildly incorrect. Changing the value to 'pipefd[0]+1' makes valgrind function correctly. I'm very surprised this worked in the terminal and gdb. I apologize for not including that, I'll edit the post to include the socketfd code so the question is better formed (so others can see the error). I'll also add the answer to the bottom and mark an answer if someone responds with one since I can't mark comments as an answer. Thank you again!

Comment: @quickblueblur - nononononono. That will still probably yield wrong results eventually; you're using the file descriptor number when calculating how many FDs are in the set, which may yield consistent results now, but will be the source of bugs later. The first argument to `select()` should be the number of file descriptors in the passed set, not whatever number `pipefd[0]+1` will return.

Comment: @slugonamission - Thank you. Look like my understanding of select and the nfds value is lacking. From the man page "nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1." For my example, I took that as using the pipefd[0] from readfs plus 1. Based on what you're saying, I should be doing the number of file descriptors (1) plus 1?

Comment: @quickblueblur - ah balls, I'm so sorry. I misread the manual page and interpreted `nfds` as literally the number of FDs. Your interpretation is correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: @slugonamission - No worries. I appreciate the help!